# Chrome html form wrong validation on select element

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, google-chrome, html-select

It seems that Chrome does not validate `<select>` in the way I expect.
Firefox returns correctly false if I select the first option while chrome does it selecting the second option. This happens both on Windows and Linux.

**My HTML**

```
<form>
<select name="select-choice" id="select-choice" required>
  <option value="">This is just a placeholder, it should invalidate the form</option>
  <option value="choice2">Choice 2</option>
  <option value="choice3">Choice 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**My JS**

```
$('form').change(function(){
   $('.result').html('form is ' + this.checkValidity());
});
```

**CodePen**

[Here is a code pen](http://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/zgDcp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would seem like a jQuery bug. If so, here is a functional vanilla/native Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="theForm">
        <select name="selectChoice" id="selectChoice" required>
            <option value="">Invalidating placeholder</option>
            <option value="choice2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice3">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script>
        var selectChoice = theForm.selectChoice;
        selectChoice.onchange = function() {
            if (selectChoice.value == '') alert('Invalid selection.');
            else alert('Valid selection.');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

.

The live example is a codepen as well: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hqutj?editors=100.

Alternatively in jQuery, you might wanna try to not use the function `checkValidity()`, which would seem to return the `options.selectedIndex`, but to check for an empty value of the `select`.

**EDIT**: on a side note: `required` seems to be an attribute that is not supported by any browser, at least not in native Javascript. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp.

Comment: This works. What still bugs me is that `checkValidity()` is not jQuery, is native JavaScript as well and [required should work](http://caniuse.com/#search=required). I ll accept this answer if nothing better comes out.

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier - cute, that `checkValidity()`. Never heard of it before, but it will make coding a lot easier. However, at this point in time, it seems to be structurally buggy due to wrong or no browser support. See http://sanalksankar.blogspot.nl/2010/12/form-validation-using-checkvalidity-and.html, the forelast paragraph. Regarding `required`: with such poor browser support (no IE8/9 and no iOS Safari), I'm gonna forget it about for now. Too busy.